# Why is it ok to use an equal sign when in analytic continuation

Tags: analytic-continuation, formal-power-series

Lets say i have the following infinite sum:
$$
\sum_n x^n
$$
then for $x<1$ we can rewrite this as
$$
\frac{1}{1-x}
$$
However often I've seen the two as equal in general (granted these are in physics papers)
$$
\sum x^n=\frac{1}{1-x} \quad \forall x\in \mathbb{C}
$$
with the phrases "as analytic continuation makes this unique" or "as a formal series".

Why is saying 'the analytic ontinuation of a is b' the same as 'a=b'?

Comment: Have you really seen $$
\sum x^n=\frac{1}{1-x} \quad \forall x\in \mathbb{C}
$$  ?

Comment: I'd appreciate a link to such a physics paper. All too often, mathematicians pretend physicists said something they didn't, especially if it involves $-\tfrac{1}{12}$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust sort of, not explicitly.  I have seen it stated and no reference to where it normally converges it mentioned (in what I am currently working on it is to do with matrices, I have formalised it in that specific instance though)

Comment: @J.G. The last thing I saw this in is page 4/5 of this https://www.math.mcgill.ca/bpym/courses/resurgence/files/resurgence-notes-01.pdf

Comment: @TobyPeterken Are you sure that's the example you wanted to link to?

Comment: Yes.  It was the example that made me write the question however I have seen similar things before

Comment: The equation is precise in the ring of formal power series $\Bbb{C}[[x]]$.